# Numpy: Memory allocations on each operation?

Tags: python, numpy

Does numpy allocate new matrices for every operation you perform on a matrix?

For example:

```
A = np.random.rand(10, 20)
A = 2 * A  # Operation 1: Is a copy of A made, and a reference assigned to A?
B = 2 * A  # Operation 2: Does B get a completely different copy of A?
C = A      # Operation 3: Does C get a reference to A?
```

And slice operations:

```
A[0, :] = 3
```

How about chained operations?

```
D = A * B * C  # Elementwise multiplication, if A * B allocates memory, does 
               # (A * B) * C allocate another patch of memory?
```

Numpy's a fantastic library, but I just want to know what happens under the hood. My intuition says that slice operations modify the memory view in place, but I don't know about assignments.

Comment: Are you concerned about speed, or about running out of memory with very large arrays?

Comment: @hpaulj: I'm concerned about speed, primarily. But memory is another thing I am mindful about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that a numpy array is a Python object.  Python creates and deletes objects continually.  The array has attributes shown in the `.FLAGS` and `.__array_interface__` dictionaries, things like the `shape` and `dtype`.  The attribute that takes up (potentially) a lot of memory is the data buffer.  It may be a few bytes long, or may be MB.

Where possible numpy operations try to avoid copying the data buffer. When indexing, it will return a `view` if possible.  I think the documentation compares views and copies well enough.

But views are different from Python references.  A shared reference means two variables (or pointers in a list or dictionary) point to the same Python object.  A `view` is a different array object, but one which shares the data buffer with another array.  A copy has its own data buffer.

In your examples:

```
A = np.random.rand(10, 20)
```

`A` is a variable pointing to an array object.  That object has a data buffer with 200 floats (200*8 bytes).

```
A = 2 * A  # Operation 1: Is a copy of A made, and a reference assigned to A?
```

`2*A` creates a new object, with a new data buffer.  None of its data values can be shared with the original `A`.  `A=...` reassigns the `A` variable.  The old `A` object is 'lost', and eventually memory is garbage collected.

```
B = 2 * A  # Operation 2: Does B get a completely different copy of A?
```

This `2*A` operates on the new `A` array.  The object is assigned to `B`.  `A` remains unchanged.

```
C = A      # Operation 3: Does C get a reference to A?
```

Yes, this is just normal Python assignment.  `C` refers to the same object as `A`.  `id(C)==id(A)`.

```
B = A[1,:]  #  B is a view
```

`B` is a reference to a new array object.  But that object shares the data buffer with `A`.  That's because the desired values can be found in the buffer by just starting at a different point, and using a different `shape`.

```
A[0, :] = 3
```

This LHS slice will change a subset of the values of `A`.  It is similar to:

```
B = A[0, :]
B = 3
```

But there are subtile differences betwee LHS and RHS slices.  On the LHS you have to pay more attention to when you get a copy as opposed to a view.  I've seen this especially with expressions like `A[idx1,:][:,idx2] = 3`.

```
D = A * B * C
```

The details of how many intermediate copies are made in a calculation like this are buried in the numpy C code.  It's safest to assume that it does something like:

```
temp1 = A*B
temp2 = temp1*C
D = temp2
(temp1 goes to garbage)
```

For ordinary calculations it isn't worth worrying about those details.  If you are really pushing for speed you could do a `timeit` on alternatives.  And occasionally we get SO questions about operations giving `memory errors`.  Do a search to get more details on those.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it creates new arrays. Except C. C and A point to same memory.

You can test all of this yourself. Try the `id(A)` command to see where in memory A is pointing. Also, just create a smaller structure and modify parts of it and then see if A, B, and/or C are also updated.

Comment: Good answer, thank you. I added a response to ask about chained operations. Do you know how numpy evaluates those?

Comment: I don't know exactly, however, in general, python interprets `D = A * B * C` as `D = A.__mul__(B).__mul__(C)` so I would assume that there is an intermediate result calculated for A * B and then again for that result * C which is finally assigned to D. You can look at the source code for numpy if you are this concerned.